# Formatting 2 column table

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I'm having trouble positioning my 2 column table. Although it looks good and everything is in order, its positioned at the top of the page instead of being underneath the correct paragraph. I'm using the IEEE document style and here is the code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Value}\\
A & Density of Degraded ECM & N/A\\
\si{\gamma} & Production Rate of Attractants & 0.5\\
M & Concentration of ECM Degrading Enzymes & N/A\\
N & Number of Tumor Cells & N/A\\
\si{X_a} & Diffusion Coefficient of Digested ECM & 0.01\\
\si{\mu_a} & Decay Rate of Digested ECM & 0.01\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: the meaning of the `table` environment is to allow the table to float to help with page breaking, you can just use `tabular` directly if you do not want it to move.

Comment: You mention in the title that you're working with a two-column table, yet the code and the screenshot seem to show a three-column table. Is either the header or the code a bit off?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem necessary or desirable to place the `tabular` material in a `table` environment, which is designed to "float" -- in a LaTeX-specific sense of the word. I would encase the tabular material in a `center` environment.

I would also (a) left-align rather than center the three columns and (b) insert a bit of whitespace between the header row and the remainder of the tabular material.

Incidentally, what is the purpose of encasing `\gamma` in an `\si` directive? At first glance, writing `$\gamma$` would seem to be more straightforward.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for \si macro
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock
\smallskip\noindent
\dots\ where the following parameters were used:
\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Value}\\[0.5ex]
A           & Density of Degraded ECM & N/A\\
\si{\gamma} & Production Rate of Attractants & 0.5\\
M           & Concentration of ECM Degrading Enzymes & N/A\\
N           & Number of Tumor Cells & N/A\\
\si{X_a}    & Diffusion Coefficient of Digested ECM & 0.01\\
\si{\mu_a}  & Decay Rate of Digested ECM & 0.01\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
Some more text after the \verb+center+ environment \dots
\end{document}
```